# Is GetApk Market application trustful?

Tags: applications, malware, alternative-markets

Is "GetApk Market" application trustful or malicious? Will it affect one's smartphone or tablet?

I have checked via [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/b9974e3f7d95eeb5d690c89a519a10a6a001b66a08e731d74233fcaf970553d3/detection) & it mostly detected as **Android.Riskware.Downloader**:

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone please help me out by confirming that, is it malicious for the tablet or not? Should I install it on the tablet?

Comment: A "score" of 11/59 from an 9 years old apk file is not inspiring confidence. If you only want to get the APK files from installed apps there are numerous alternatives from apps with a better reputation.

Comment: Do you want a TOTAL STRANGER, someone you've never met, and cannot verify the trustworthiness of, to say "YES INSTALL IT" to make you feel safe? Sure, I'll do that for you. R-r-r-i-i-i-ght.

Answer (score 3):

GetAPK seems to specialize in warez. It takes pride in hosting paid Apps from Play Store for free. Putting aside the blatant violation of intellectual property rights for the moment, paid Apps for free are infamously known to infiltrate the user's device as a malware.

It would be unwise to proceed installing such app even if Virustotal doesn't show anything suspicious. However, curiosity sometimes cannot be put to rest, so if you want to test this app, I suggest you try it in a virtual machine in a PC using Android-x86 or the likes of it.

You can also use a disposable Android device and see how well the app is behaving. Even than, that could only increase your confidence slightly. The risk would always linger as long as you continue to use such an app.

In short, if you plan to install paid Apps for free whether directly or via a market, be prepared to have your data (assume everything that rests or is loaded in the phone) misused and taken hostage.

Comment: What about those kinds of apps (from getapk market) which don't want extra permission ? If they don't want permission of storage or something, is there any possibility to be misused of data or taken as hostage ?

Comment: You seriously mis-understand the point here. GetAPK can itself compromise your system. It is best to avoid it at first place. It is not worth the risk.